# Uninstalling MSXML 4 from SharePoint 2010 Servers

Tags: sharepoint-server

Our security team has come up with a report stating that there is still MSXML 4 on the servers which EOL. I did check the syswow64 folder and I see MSXML 6 and MSXML 3. If I go ahead and uninstall MSXML 4 from the SharePoint server, would it create a impact? Many sites talk about renaming the MSXML4.dll to old, is it ok doing that after uninstalling or just renaming without uninstalling would be a good approach?I am trying to play safe by not deleting the DLL and just renaming it.

Please advice.